# How can i remove a class from a div when both of three input fields are filled?

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 input fields and a specific div. What i want is to remove the class "disable" from this div only when the 3 input fields are filled using jquery.

My problem is that if you enter something in the field "title" it removes instantly the class "disable" from the div, ignoring the other 2 empty fields.

Here's also a  [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3s1gn3r/nt2ecr90/)

```js
$('#price' && '#category' && '#title').on('keyup', function(){
$("#next-btn1").toggleClass('disable', $('#price' && '#category' && '#title').val()==''); 
})
```

```css
#next-btn1 {
  margin-top:20px;
  background:#0088cc;
  color:#ffffff;
  width:150px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  height:48px;
  line-height:48px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:1em;
  margin-left:10px;
}

#price, #category, #title {
  height:43px;
  line-height:43px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#585858;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:1em;
  margin-bottom:8px;
}

.disable {
  color:#aaa!important;
  background:#ddd!important;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" id="price" placeholder="Enter Product Price"/> 
<input autocomplete="off" id="category" placeholder="Enter a category"/>
<input autocomplete="off" id="title" placeholder="Enter your title"/> 
<div class="disable"  id="next-btn1">
  Next Step
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post all relevant code in the question itself

Comment: i already posted the jsfiddle

Comment: Yes, but that's a *link*, not *code*, unfortunately

Comment: ok i m pasting the code here

Comment: i really can't understand why is the downvoting for...

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you please take a look now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a common class to your input fields like `inputField` and then change your jquery to this.

```
$('.inputField').on('keyup', function(){
    if($('#price').val() == '' || $('#category').val() == '' || $('#title').val() == '') {
    $("#next-btn1").addClass('disable');
  }else {
    $("#next-btn1").removeClass('disable');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked as it should. I just wonder why my question is downvoted as it is useful and clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Try Following**

add same class to yous textbox & call event on that class

```js
$(document).on('keyup mouseleave','.ChechValue', function(){
ChechValue()
});
function ChechValue()
{
if($('#price').val().trim()!='' && $('#category').val().trim()!='' && $('#title').val().trim()!='')
{
$("#next-btn1").removeClass('disable');
}
else
{
$("#next-btn1").addClass('disable');
}
}
```

```css
#next-btn1 {
  margin-top:20px;
  background:#0088cc;
  color:#ffffff;
  width:150px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  height:48px;
  line-height:48px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:1em;
  margin-left:10px;
}

#price, #category, #title {
  height:43px;
  line-height:43px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#585858;
  display:block;
  font-size:1em;
  margin-bottom:8px;
}

.disable {
  color:#aaa!important;
  background:#ddd!important;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" class="ChechValue" id="price" placeholder="Enter Product Price"/> 
<input autocomplete="off" class="ChechValue" id="category" placeholder="Enter a category"/>
<input autocomplete="off" class="ChechValue" id="title" placeholder="Enter your title"/> 
<div class="disable"  id="next-btn1">
  Next Step
</div>
```

Comment: but your code not works when I use the mouse to copy and paste in the textbox.